# Restrict only numbers in TextField in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I want to enter only numbers in Textfield. I tried this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72712145/11560810) logic to restrict alphabet and special characters but when I press dot in my keyboard it's crash.

**Error**

```
2022-08-18 09:47:13.966 8050-8050/com.abc.app.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.abc.app.dev, PID: 8050
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "."
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:733)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:865)
        at com.abc.app.yo.composable.InputKt$InputWithUnitContainer$1$1$1$1.invoke(Input.kt:187)
        at com.abc.app.yo.composable.InputKt$InputWithUnitContainer$1$1$1$1.invoke(Input.kt:186)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicTextFieldKt$BasicTextField$7$1.invoke(BasicTextField.kt:266)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicTextFieldKt$BasicTextField$7$1.invoke(BasicTextField.kt:264)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.CoreTextFieldKt$CoreTextField$onValueChangeWrapper$1.invoke(CoreTextField.kt:241)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.CoreTextFieldKt$CoreTextField$onValueChangeWrapper$1.invoke(CoreTextField.kt:236)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldDelegate$Companion.onEditCommand(TextFieldDelegate.kt:198)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldDelegate$Companion.access$onEditCommand(TextFieldDelegate.kt:90)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldDelegate$Companion$restartInput$1.invoke(TextFieldDelegate.kt:246)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldDelegate$Companion$restartInput$1.invoke(TextFieldDelegate.kt:243)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextInputServiceAndroid$createInputConnection$1.onEditCommands(TextInputServiceAndroid.android.kt:111)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.RecordingInputConnection.endBatchEditInternal(RecordingInputConnection.android.kt:162)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.RecordingInputConnection.addEditCommandWithBatch(RecordingInputConnection.android.kt:136)
        at androidx.compose.ui.text.input.RecordingInputConnection.commitText(RecordingInputConnection.android.kt:181)
        at com.android.internal.inputmethod.RemoteInputConnectionImpl.lambda$commitText$16$com-android-internal-inputmethod-RemoteInputConnectionImpl(RemoteInputConnectionImpl.java:569)
        at com.android.internal.inputmethod.RemoteInputConnectionImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda34.run(Unknown Source:8)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

**Code**

```
appendTextFieldValue: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
```

this is passing through function and below is my Textfield

```
        TextField(
                value = textFieldValue,
                singleLine = true,
                onValueChange = {
                    if (it.text.length <= maxLength && it.text.toInt() <= maxLength) {
                        appendTextFieldValue(it)
                    }
                    onIsErrorChange(false)
                },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
                isError = isError,
            )
```

Comment: Do you want only numbers or also digital number?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I want numbers like 12345678.... I don't know about digital number. What is difference in numbers and digital number?

Comment: my bad sorry. number with decimals

Comment: I don't need decimals only numbers..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use a regex pattern.

Something like:

```
val pattern = remember { Regex("^\\d+\$") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isEmpty() || it.matches(pattern)) {
            text = it
        }
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
)
```

Comment: one problem occurs when you have one text you cannot use backspace to remove the digit.

Comment: @vivekmodi Answer updated.

Comment: It's possible to modify regex to zero or more digits `Regex("^\\d*\$")` and you can remove `it.isEmpty()` from the if condition.

Comment: In fact, after controlling with regex, there is no need to add keyboard Options because we only make changes when the number is entered. Isn't?

Answer (score 6):

This is what I do to achieve this:

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { if (it.isDigitsOnly()) text = it },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can filter string like`

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isEmpty()) {
            text = it.filter { symbol ->
                symbol.isDigit()
            }
        }
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
)
```

Comment: I just want to  input positive int number, This is the right way, thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show the keyboard with only numbers, simply do this:

```
TextField(
     value = textState,
     onValueChange = { text ->
         textState = text
     },
     keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
         keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword
     ),
     visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict your text field to digits only

```
var amount by remember { mutableStateOf("") }    
TextField(value = amount, onValueChange = {if (it.isDigitsOnly()) amount = it}
```